# How to insert a deep link into an FCM notification using the new Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, deep-linking, firebase-admin

I just want to create a notification that execute a deep link when it's clicked using Firebase Admin SDKs. I found a solution but it doesn't seem clean

Firebase Admin SDK Python:

```
messaging.send(messaging.Message(
    notification=messaging.Notification(
        title='test title',
        body='test body',
    ),
    android=messaging.AndroidConfig(
        notification=messaging.AndroidNotification(
            click_action='example://deep.link',
        ),
    ),
    token='.....',
))
```

Android Client Side:

```
private const val CLICK_ACTION = "gcm.notification.click_action"

class FirebaseMessagingService : com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun handleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        intent?.getStringExtra(CLICK_ACTION)?.let {
            if (Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(it).matches()) {
                intent.putExtra(Constants.MessageNotificationKeys.LINK_ANDROID, it)
                intent.removeExtra(CLICK_ACTION)
            }
        }
        super.handleIntent(intent)
    }
}
```

My solution is based on reverse enginering of Android FCM library https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/firebase-messaging/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/messaging/CommonNotificationBuilder.java#L399

Why in new SDK there isn't anymore the param "link" or "link_android" ?